# Qual a diferença entre SOAP 1.1 e SOAP 1.2?

Tags: web-service, xml, soap

Quando eu uso o SOAP UI ( http://www.soapui.org/ ) e referencio aos meus webServices asmx, ele sempre cria a interface das operações para SOAP 1.1 e 1.2. E não percebo qual é a diferença prática. Pra mim o resultado é o mesmo.

O que tem de diferente entre SOAP 1.1 e SOAP 1.2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algumas diferenças:

**SOAP 1.1** é baseado em `XML 1.0` enquanto o **SOAP 1.2** em `XML Information Set (Infoset XML)`. O conjunto de informações `XML (infoset)` fornece uma maneira de descrever o documento `XML` com esquema [`XSD`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema). Esta maneira de descrever o documento `XML` ajuda revelar outros formatos de "serialização", como por exemplo um protocolo de formato binário.

**SOAP 1.2** fornece a capacidade de definir oficialmente protocolos de transporte, exceto usando o `HTTP`, enquanto o fornecedor está em conformidade com a estrutura de ligação que é definida em **SOAP 1.2**.Enquanto `HTTP` é onipresente, não é tão confiável quanto outros transportes, incluindo `TCP/IP` e `MQ`. **SOAP 1.2** fornece uma definição mais específica do modelo de processamento SOAP que remove muitas das ambiguidades que podem levar a erros de interoperabilidade, na ausência dos perfis **Web Services-Interoperability (WS-I)**. As grandes diferenças são praticamente maiores e significativas em **SOAP 1.2**, uma evlolução na forma de consumir e fornecer.

Answer (score 4):

**A versão SOAP 1.2 pode fazer tudo o que SOAP 1.1 faz, e muito mais.**

SOAP 1.2 mais limpo, possui melhor integração Web, mais versátil e mais rápido:

1. **Mais limpo**: modelos de processamento e de extensibilidade claras,
   maior interoperabilidade.
2. **Melhor integração Web**: uma melhor integração com os padrões XML e da arquitetura da Web.
3. **Mais versátil**: proporciona independência de protocolo fornecendo um
   binding framework.
4. **Mais rápido**: baseado em XML Infoset permitindo
   otimização de desempenho.

[**Aqui você terá as informações mais detalhadas**](http://www.w3.org/2003/06/soap11-soap12.html).